# couldn't install bcrypt with npm

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I tried installing bcrypt by `npm install bcrypt` but fails with `503 Service Unavailable`.

```
Error: 503 Service Unavailable - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev - Service Unavailable
```

The log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'i', 'bcrypt' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.1
4 verbose npm-session 123d0e98c6b4c75b
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt 230ms
8 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt/-/bcrypt-5.0.1.tgz 71ms
9 silly pacote tag manifest for bcrypt@latest fetched in 315ms
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 470ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 1ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 119ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 silly resolveWithNewModule bcrypt@5.0.1 checking installable status
18 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-addon-api 146ms
19 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-addon-api/-/node-addon-api-3.2.1.tgz 63ms
20 silly pacote range manifest for node-addon-api@^3.1.0 fetched in 213ms
21 silly resolveWithNewModule node-addon-api@3.2.1 checking installable status
22 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@mapbox%2fnode-pre-gyp 377ms
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/-/node-pre-gyp-1.0.7.tgz 101ms
24 silly pacote range manifest for @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@^1.0.0 fetched in 492ms
25 silly resolveWithNewModule @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.7 checking installable status
26 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-libc 67ms
27 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent 69ms
28 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent/-/https-proxy-agent-5.0.0.tgz 55ms
29 silly pacote range manifest for https-proxy-agent@^5.0.0 fetched in 136ms
30 silly resolveWithNewModule https-proxy-agent@5.0.0 checking installable status
31 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-libc/-/detect-libc-1.0.3.tgz 69ms
32 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog 138ms
33 silly pacote range manifest for detect-libc@^1.0.3 fetched in 144ms
34 silly resolveWithNewModule detect-libc@1.0.3 checking installable status
35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 153ms
36 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/make-dir 157ms
37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver 155ms
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt 178ms
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-fetch 190ms
40 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog/-/npmlog-6.0.0.tgz 59ms
41 silly pacote range manifest for npmlog@^6.0.0 fetched in 200ms
42 silly resolveWithNewModule npmlog@6.0.0 checking installable status
43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/make-dir/-/make-dir-3.1.0.tgz 55ms
44 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-3.0.2.tgz 58ms
45 silly pacote range manifest for make-dir@^3.1.0 fetched in 229ms
46 silly resolveWithNewModule make-dir@3.1.0 checking installable status
47 silly pacote range manifest for rimraf@^3.0.2 fetched in 229ms
48 silly resolveWithNewModule rimraf@3.0.2 checking installable status
49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-7.3.5.tgz 69ms
50 silly pacote range manifest for semver@^7.3.5 fetched in 231ms
51 silly resolveWithNewModule semver@7.3.5 checking installable status
52 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-5.0.0.tgz 65ms
53 silly pacote range manifest for nopt@^5.0.0 fetched in 247ms
54 silly resolveWithNewModule nopt@5.0.0 checking installable status
55 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-fetch/-/node-fetch-2.6.6.tgz 54ms
56 silly pacote range manifest for node-fetch@^2.6.5 fetched in 249ms
57 silly resolveWithNewModule node-fetch@2.6.6 checking installable status
58 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar 107955ms attempt #3
59 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-6.1.11.tgz 63ms
60 silly pacote range manifest for tar@^6.1.11 fetched in 108025ms
61 silly resolveWithNewModule tar@6.1.11 checking installable status
62 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/agent-base 64ms
63 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/agent-base/-/agent-base-6.0.2.tgz 52ms
64 silly pacote range manifest for agent-base@6 fetched in 120ms
65 silly resolveWithNewModule agent-base@6.0.2 checking installable status
66 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 176ms (from cache)
67 silly pacote range manifest for debug@4 fetched in 178ms
68 silly resolveWithNewModule debug@4.3.3 checking installable status
69 silly pacote range manifest for debug@4 fetched in 1ms
70 silly resolveWithNewModule debug@4.3.3 checking installable status
71 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms 54ms (from cache)
72 silly pacote version manifest for ms@2.1.2 fetched in 56ms
73 silly resolveWithNewModule ms@2.1.2 checking installable status
74 silly pacote version manifest for ms@2.1.2 fetched in 0ms
75 silly resolveWithNewModule ms@2.1.2 checking installable status
76 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-6.3.0.tgz 59ms
77 silly pacote range manifest for semver@^6.0.0 fetched in 64ms
78 silly resolveWithNewModule semver@6.3.0 checking installable status
79 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/whatwg-url 63ms (from cache)
80 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/whatwg-url/-/whatwg-url-5.0.0.tgz 50ms
81 silly pacote range manifest for whatwg-url@^5.0.0 fetched in 116ms
82 silly resolveWithNewModule whatwg-url@5.0.0 checking installable status
83 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tr46 64ms (from cache)
84 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tr46/-/tr46-0.0.3.tgz 61ms
85 silly pacote range manifest for tr46@~0.0.3 fetched in 128ms
86 silly resolveWithNewModule tr46@0.0.3 checking installable status
87 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webidl-conversions 33507ms attempt #2
88 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webidl-conversions/-/webidl-conversions-3.0.1.tgz 56ms
89 silly pacote range manifest for webidl-conversions@^3.0.0 fetched in 33568ms
90 silly resolveWithNewModule webidl-conversions@3.0.1 checking installable status
91 http fetch GET 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev 125103ms attempt #3
92 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for abbrev@1 503 Service Unavailable - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev - Service Unavailable
93 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
94 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 268235ms
95 silly saveTree backend@1.0.0
95 silly saveTree ├─┬ bcrypt@5.0.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.7
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── detect-libc@1.0.3
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ https-proxy-agent@5.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ ├─┬ agent-base@6.0.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ │ └─┬ debug@4.3.3
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ │   └── ms@2.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └─┬ debug@4.3.3
95 silly saveTree │ │ │   └── ms@2.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ make-dir@3.1.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── semver@6.3.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ node-fetch@2.6.6
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └─┬ whatwg-url@5.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ │   ├── tr46@0.0.3
95 silly saveTree │ │ │   └── webidl-conversions@3.0.1
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── nopt@5.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── npmlog@6.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── rimraf@3.0.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── semver@7.3.5
95 silly saveTree │ │ └── tar@6.1.11
95 silly saveTree │ └── node-addon-api@3.2.1
95 silly saveTree ├─┬ express-validator@6.14.0
95 silly saveTree │ ├── lodash@4.17.21
95 silly saveTree │ └── validator@13.7.0
95 silly saveTree ├─┬ express@4.17.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.7
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.34
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── mime-db@1.51.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ └── negotiator@0.6.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ body-parser@1.19.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── bytes@3.1.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── content-type@1.0.4
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.7.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.1
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ ├── statuses@1.5.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── toidentifier@1.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ iconv-lite@0.4.24
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── safer-buffer@2.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── qs@6.7.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ raw-body@2.4.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ └─┬ type-is@1.6.18
95 silly saveTree │ │   └── media-typer@0.3.0
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ content-disposition@0.5.3
95 silly saveTree │ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├── content-type@1.0.4
95 silly saveTree │ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
95 silly saveTree │ ├── cookie@0.4.0
95 silly saveTree │ ├── debug@2.6.9
95 silly saveTree │ ├── depd@1.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
95 silly saveTree │ ├── etag@1.8.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ finalhandler@1.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ │ └── parseurl@1.3.3
95 silly saveTree │ ├── fresh@0.5.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├── methods@1.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0
95 silly saveTree │ ├── parseurl@1.3.3
95 silly saveTree │ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ proxy-addr@2.0.7
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── forwarded@0.2.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.9.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├── qs@6.7.0
95 silly saveTree │ ├── range-parser@1.2.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2
95 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ send@0.17.1
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
95 silly saveTree │ │ ├── mime@1.6.0
95 silly saveTree │ │ └── ms@2.1.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├── serve-static@1.14.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.1
95 silly saveTree │ ├── statuses@1.5.0
95 silly saveTree │ ├── type-is@1.6.18
95 silly saveTree │ ├── utils-merge@1.0.1
95 silly saveTree │ └── vary@1.1.2
95 silly saveTree └─┬ mongoose@6.1.2
95 silly saveTree   ├─┬ bson@4.6.0
95 silly saveTree   │ └─┬ buffer@5.7.1
95 silly saveTree   │   ├── base64-js@1.5.1
95 silly saveTree   │   └── ieee754@1.2.1
95 silly saveTree   ├── kareem@2.3.2
95 silly saveTree   ├─┬ mongodb@4.2.2
95 silly saveTree   │ ├── denque@2.0.1
95 silly saveTree   │ ├─┬ mongodb-connection-string-url@2.3.2
95 silly saveTree   │ │ ├─┬ @types/whatwg-url@8.2.1
95 silly saveTree   │ │ │ ├── @types/node@16.11.13
95 silly saveTree   │ │ │ └── @types/webidl-conversions@6.1.1
95 silly saveTree   │ │ └─┬ whatwg-url@11.0.0
95 silly saveTree   │ │   ├─┬ tr46@3.0.0
95 silly saveTree   │ │   │ └── punycode@2.1.1
95 silly saveTree   │ │   └── webidl-conversions@7.0.0
95 silly saveTree   │ └─┬ saslprep@1.0.3
95 silly saveTree   │   └─┬ sparse-bitfield@3.0.3
95 silly saveTree   │     └── memory-pager@1.5.0
95 silly saveTree   ├── mpath@0.8.4
95 silly saveTree   ├─┬ mquery@4.0.0
95 silly saveTree   │ ├─┬ debug@4.3.3
95 silly saveTree   │ │ └── ms@2.1.2
95 silly saveTree   │ ├── regexp-clone@1.0.0
95 silly saveTree   │ └── sliced@1.0.1
95 silly saveTree   ├── ms@2.1.2
95 silly saveTree   ├── regexp-clone@1.0.0
95 silly saveTree   ├── sift@13.5.2
95 silly saveTree   └── sliced@1.0.1
96 verbose stack Error: 503 Service Unavailable - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev - Service Unavailable
96 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:117:15
96 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
96 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
97 verbose statusCode 503
98 verbose pkgid abbrev@1
99 verbose cwd /Users/saikrishnadas/mern/server
100 verbose Darwin 21.1.0
101 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "bcrypt"
102 verbose node v14.17.1
103 verbose npm  v6.14.13
104 error code E503
105 error 503 Service Unavailable - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev - Service Unavailable
106 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `Error: 503 Service Unavailable - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev - Service Unavailable` If it’s down there’s not much we can do about it.

Comment: So any alternative for bcrypt ?

Comment: The package is irrelevant: npm is down. You can download whatever lib you want, just not from npm until it’s back up.

Comment: @DaveNewton But I could install other ( npm i mongoose and express worked in my case)

Comment: Not at the moment you can’t. npm is down.

Comment: @DaveNewton I meant I was able to install mongoose and express with npm

Comment: npm is down. delete them and try installing it again—did it work?

Comment: It's back up, try again.

Comment: (I’m gonna pretend it’s down for another hour :D